# iOS parse string with multiple JSON objects?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm having some troubles when my app receives multiple JSON objects at the same time. I'm using a TCP socket that is open to my server which sends me messages. The reason i seem to recieve multiple messages is probably due to network lag.

This is what a server message can look like (i then put this into a NSString and try to parse the JSON):

```
{
    "id": "156806",
    "type": "message",
    "userCity": "",
    "userCountry": "",
    "os": "",
    "browser": "",
    "trafficType": "",
    "seKeyword": "",
    "seType": "",
    "currentPage": "",
    "userId": "1",
    "agentId": "352",
    "customField1": "",
    "visitorNick": "Visitor 147220060",
    "msg": "asd",
    "time": "16:05",
    "channel": "V147220060",
    "visits": "254"
} {
    "type": "previewStopped",
    "msg": "",
    "visitorNick": "Mackan",
    "customField1": "",
    "visitorNick": "Visitor V147220060",
    "time": "16:05",
    "channel": "V147220060"
} {
    "id": "156807",
    "type": "message",
    "userCity": "",
    "userCountry": "",
    "os": "",
    "browser": "",
    "trafficType": "",
    "seKeyword": "",
    "seType": "",
    "currentPage": "",
    "userId": "1",
    "agentId": "352",
    "customField1": "",
    "visitorNick": "Visitor 147220060",
    "msg": "as",
    "time": "16:05",
    "channel": "V147220060",
    "visits": "254"
} {
    "id": "156808",
    "type": "message",
    "userCity": "",
    "userCountry": "",
    "os": "",
    "browser": "",
    "trafficType": "",
    "seKeyword": "",
    "seType": "",
    "currentPage": "",
    "userId": "1",
    "agentId": "352",
    "customField1": "",
    "visitorNick": "Visitor 147220060",
    "msg": "da",
    "time": "16:05",
    "channel": "V147220060",
    "visits": "254"
}
```

And here is how i currently parse the NSString, note that the above JSON is `outputData` in the code below:

```
            // Parse the message from the server
            NSError* error;
            NSDictionary *JSON =
            [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData: [outputData dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]
                                            options: NSJSONReadingMutableContainers
                                              error: &error];


            NSString* type = [JSON objectForKey:@"type"];

            if(error) {
                NSLog(@"PARSE ERROR ------------->>>>> : %@\n", error);
            }

            NSLog(@"SERVER TYPE --> %@\n", type);

            if([type isEqualToString:@"message"]) {                    
                [self messageReceived:outputData];
            }
```

The above works perfectly when i only recieve one JSON in `outputData` but when multiple JSONs are recieved it trows an error:

> PARSE ERROR ------------->>>>> : Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain
>   Code=3840 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 3840.)"
>   (Garbage at end.) UserInfo=0x14e9acb0 {NSDebugDescription=Garbage at
>   end.}

Any ideas how to handle this?

Comment: Can you add the output of `[outputData dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]`?

Comment: It is unusual to get multiple JSON entities in one package.  Usually the server wraps it up into one JSON array with the multiple entities being an item in the array. Can you get the server to wrap your JSON entities into a single JSON structure?  Failing that, you'll have to parse out the JSON yourself and feed them to the parser one at a time.

Comment: @yoeriboven not sure i follow, what variable do you want me to echo to the console?

Comment: Try changing `NSJSONReadingMutableContainers` to `NSJSONReadingAllowFragments`

Comment: Quick check... is your means of storing received messages threadsafe? That is, you should probably have your main thread accept and a separate thread processes the JSON request (via a threadsafe queue). That is, the main thread just adds raw messages to a threadsafe queue while the second thread reads from the queue, processing what it finds.

Comment: @Eugene still get same error

Comment: @wmorrison365 I'm using a RunLoop to read data from the TCP socket

Comment: @OwenHartnett The server does not wrap it into an array, unfortunately

Comment: Your server returns false information, what you posted is not a valid json, it should be delimited in commas and wrapped in an array brackets [{"id":1}, {"id":2}]. You also want to assign the result into an NSAray, instead of NSDictionary. Validate your json vs jsonlint.com

Comment: I cant change what i recieve from the server, is there a way for me to insert this afterwards? Maybe look for `} {` and insert a `,` in between?

Comment: Echo `outputData` to the console so we can see if it is a valid string your server returns.

Answer (score 1):

Hmm...you could wrap it yourself.  Take the data you get and prepend `"{ "dataarray": ["`  to the beginning, and `"] }"` to the end.  This will produce an array, the elements of which will be your individual JSON entities.

Comment: You're forgetting the commas for }{ brackets

Comment: Yes, you should also look for } { and insert commas, but you should match braces and only do it at the top level.

Comment: Run a counter to increment for every { and decrement for every } and insert commas at those points where your counter goes to zero.  You can convert the data to an NSMutableString and that class should give you a ton of methods for changing the contents.

Comment: How would that look in code? Not entirely sure how to write it

Comment: the simplest way is a for loop over every character.  Have a variable initialized to zero. When you encounter a {, increment the variable, when you encounter a }, decrement it.  When you reach zero it means you've matched the beginning {, so if you encounter after that another {, then insert a comma first.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
NSData *jsonData = [outputData dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSArray *dict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:0 error:&e];
NSDictionary *JSON = [dict objectAtIndex:0];
NSString* type = [JSON objectForKey:@"type"];
```

**EDIT:**

An example of JSON, because your "" can cause problems:

```
{
    aula = "AULA M04";
    cuatrimestre = "Primer quadrimestre";
    dia = Dimecres;
    edificio = "AULARI V";
    fin = "18:00";
    inicio = "15:00";
}
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

It's erroring out because you don't have valid JSON in your string. You'll need to do something like the following to get it into the correct format:

```
NSString *formattedString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"[%@]", [outputData stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"} {" withString:@"},{"]];

NSError *error = nil;
NSArray *JSON = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:[formattedString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:&error];
```

That is assuming `outputData` is an `NSString`.

Answer (score 0):

If your data stream contains multiple JSONs in sequence, it strictly isn't JSON anymore. Rather, it is a *custom* protocol which embeds JSON.

You need to first define your custom protocol. It can be defined as an arbitrary number of JSONs in sequence - if this fits your needs. `NSJSONSerialization` isn't capable to  parse your *custom* protocol, though.

You could define your protocol differently, for example: your data is a contiguous stream of *messages*, where a message is a "blob" prepended by value representing the length in bytes, e.g.:

```
message := message_size CRLF blob   

message_size   :=  digits

data :=   message*
```

That is, your data may look as follows:

```
2\n\r[]4\n\r5["a"]
```

This is of course a pretty naive protocol, but it should be sufficient to demonstrate the basic idea.

Your blob could then be JSON UTF-8.

This "protocol" can be easily parsed with a custom parser, where the "blob" (a single JSON) will be passed through a JSON parser, possibly wrapped into a `NSData` object.